# Generate dataframe from pandas groupby object with apply function returning multiple values

Tags: python, pandas

Sample Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[0,1,2,3], [0,1,3,4], [0,2,5,6], [0,2,7,8]], columns=['id1', 'id2', 'var1', 'var2'])
```

[image: df]

function f:

```
def f(var1, var2):
    return [np.sum(var1)*10, np.sum(var2)*10]
```

output needed:

[image: result_df]

The method I have used to generate this is:

```
result_df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['id1', 'id2'])['var1', 'var2'].apply(lambda x: f(x['var1'], x['var2'])))
pd.DataFrame(result_df[0].tolist(), columns=['result_var1', 'result_var2'], index=result_df.index).reset_index()
```

Is there any better method available to generate a dataframe by applying a function on a pandas groupby object, and the function returns multiple values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
result = df.groupby(['id1', 'id2'], as_index=False).agg(lambda x: x.sum() * 10)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
   id1  id2  var1  var2
0    0    1    50    70
1    0    2   120   140
```

A more general application of agg is the following:

```
def general_var1(x):
    return x.sum() * 10


def general_var2(x):
    return x.sum() * 5 + 2


result = df.groupby(['id1', 'id2'], as_index=False).agg({'var1': general_var1, 'var2': general_var2})
```

**Output**

```
   id1  id2  var1  var2
0    0    1    50    37
1    0    2   120    72
```

More examples can be found in the linked documentation.

Comment: what if the function is not as simple as the one mentioned above? Can I use .agg(lambda x: f(x[0], f[1])) in general?

Comment: You can define the function you want as long as if it is the same function for all columns. Note that agg also support the case for multiple for functions for the same column and multiple functions for different columns.

Comment: Can you please modify your answer for a general function output case?

Comment: @bazinga updated the question with a more meaningful example

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
(df.groupby(['id1', 'id2']).sum() * 10).reset_index()

Out[247]:
   id1  id2  var1  var2
0    0    1    50    70
1    0    2   120   140
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need it exactly as you have it (with even the column names changed), use the code below.

```
(df.groupby(['id1', 'id2'])['var1', 'var2'].sum()*10).add_prefix('result_').reset_index()
```

**Output**

```
   id1  id2     result_var1     result_var2
0   0   1             50        70
1   0   2             120       140
```